# The function find_elements() returns an empty list

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get a list of multiples elements but every time I use find_elements(By.XXX ''), I can't succeed to select anything, I tried using name, id, class and css selector but every time I get an empty list. The site I am trying to get information from is private but  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsXJO.png) is a screen of the elements I want to get (ideally I want to have the text because anytime I open the page the question order changes between these questions, being able to read the question can lead me to automatize my answer). I also tried getting all the IDs one by one

```
listID = ['h5p-tfq0','h5p-tfq1','h5p-tfq2','h5p-tfq3','h5p-tfq4','h5p-tfq5','h5p-tfq6','h5p-tfq7','h5p-mcq0','h5p-mcq1']
    for id in listID :
        content = driver.find_elements(By.ID,id)
        if content != [] :
            print(content)
```

but I can't get anything in my list.

(I think all the needed imports are here but I may be wrong so I'll let you see them)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

Comment: Most likely, the data you are trying to scrape from the page is not loaded at the time of fetching, or is generated by Ajax/JS calls that you do not simulate inside the code, but without actual page we can just guess.

Comment: You should use explicit waits for those elements. More, those IDs seem dynamically generated, so you should use different locators for those elements. Not much to help you with, considering you cannot provide the URL.

Comment: Try this: content = driver.find_elements(By.ID,''h5p-")